# c++ Función float retorna un entero

Tags: c++

tengo un problema con este ejercicio, es muy sencillo pero evidentemente hay algo que estoy pasando por alto y por eso no obtengo el resultado que espero.

```
float calcularPorcentajeDiferencia(int a, int b) //NO FUNCIONA!! retorna un int y no un float 
{
    if (a+b==0)
       cout << "El calculo no es posible." << endl;
    else {
        return (b-a) *100 / (a+b);
    }

    
}

int main()
{
    float num1, num2;
   

    cout << "Ingrese dos valores: ";
    cin >> num1 >> num2;
    
    cout << "El porcentaje de la diferencia entre " << num1 << " y " << num2 << " es: " <<calcularPorcentajeDiferencia (num1, num2) << endl;



    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Está retornando un `float` pero no está incluyendo los decimales porque está operando dos enteros y las operaciones entre enteros producen resultados enteros.

Cambia los tipos de los parámetros a `float`.

```
float calcularPorcentajeDiferencia(float a, float b) 
{
    if (a+b==0)
       cout << "El calculo no es posible." << endl;
    else {
        return (b-a) *100 / (a+b);
    }

    
}
```

Comment: Clarooo ahora entiendo, muchas gracias!!